# Modify global variable in Javascript inside geocode

Tags: javascript, variables, google-maps-markers, global, geocode

I'm getting crazy with this.

```
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            locations[j][0] = direcciones[j]['1'];
            locations[j][1] = latitude;
            locations[j][2] = longitude;
            locations[j][3] = direcciones[j]['10'];
            j++;

        } 
        });
```

If I do an alert of locations[0][0] inside geocode function, it works fine, but if I do it out, i get the previous value, because I am not modifying global locations variable...

Someone could help me to chenge correctly that variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...but if I do it out, i get the previous value, because I am not modifying global locations variable...

Yes, it is, it's just doing it **later**. The call to `geocode` is *asynchronous*, and so won't see the result until the callback is made. Code immediately after the `geocode` function call will run *before* the callback runs, and so you won't see any change.

Let's use a simpler example for illustration:

```
// A variable we'll change
var x = 1;

// Do something asynchronous; we'll use `setTimeout` but `geocode` is asynchronous as well
setTimeout(function() {
    // Change the value
    x = 2;
    console.log(Date.now() + ": x = " + x + " (in callback)");
}, 10);
console.log(Date.now() + ": x = " + x + " (immediately after setTimeout call)");
```

If you run that ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sL9gn/)), you'll see something like this:

```
1400063937865: x = 1 (immediately after setTimeout call)
1400063937915: x = 2 (in callback)
```

Note what happened first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll make a jQuery function and i'll get the success. It is the only method I know.

Thanks!